# Active MQ : org.apache.activemq.AlreadyClosedException: this connection

Tags: spring, activemq-classic

Recently I have updated Spring version 4.2.4.RELEASE from 3.2.1.RELEASE
I was using `JmsTemplatez to convert and send message as:

```
jmsTemplate.convertAndSend(request, new CorrelationIdPostProcessor(request.getMessageId(), messageQueueAuditLogger));
```

After the upgrade to Spring 4.2.4.RELEASE I started to get an exception:

```
org.springframework.jms.UncategorizedJmsException: Uncategorized exception occured during JMS processing; nested exception is org.apache.activemq.AlreadyClosedException: this connection
        at org.springframework.jms.support.JmsUtils.convertJmsAccessException(JmsUtils.java:316)    
Caused by: org.apache.activemq.AlreadyClosedException: this connection
        at org.apache.activemq.pool.PooledConnection.assertNotClosed(PooledConnection.java:161)
        at org.apache.activemq.pool.PooledConnection.start(PooledConnection.java:77)
        at org.springframework.jms.connection.SingleConnectionFactory$SharedConnectionInvocationHandler.localStart(SingleConnectionFactory.java:632)
        at org.springframework.jms.connection.SingleConnectionFactory$SharedConnectionInvocationHandler.invoke(SingleConnectionFactory.java:569)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy52.start(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.execute(JmsTemplate.java:487)
```

Active MQ version in use: 5.4.2

If any one has came across this error please share your comments.

Comment: I didn't understand why to edit the exception trace etc ???

Answer (score 0):

Previously I was using org.apache.activemq.pool.PooledConnectionFactory which is causing this exception. I have replaced PooledConnectionFactory with org.springframework.jms.connection.SingleConnectionFactory and this has resolved the problem